# How to transmit characters or just use xbee like serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, xbee

I have an arduino mega and an uno, mega has an xbee s2c as coordinator and uno an xbee s2c as router, both in AT ( transparent ) mode. When I send integers from uno with Serial.write() coordinator receives just fine, but when i try float, negative numbers and chars, i get still integers but as I found out sending chars it is in ASCII. I tried Serial.print() but no result. Is there a way to send a negative float from one xbee to the other in AT mode?

Coordinator code

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Comersing test!");
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial1.available()>0){
         Serial.print(Serial1.read());
    }
}`
```

UNO code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 SoftwareSerial xbSerial(8, 7); // RX, TX
void setup() {
  xbSerial.begin(9600);
  xbSerial.write("First data sent!");

}
int x=4;
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      xbSerial.write(x);
      x++;
      delay(1000);
      delay(1000);
      delay(1000);
}
```

if I change x in Uno to float, negative or char, I get weird values.

Comment: If you can send ASCII and you have control over both ends of the data then you could send the numbers as text strings (not very efficient).  If the number have a limited range i.e. -127 -> +127 then you could send 0 when you wanted to transmit -127, 1 for -126, etc.

Answer (score -1):

XBee cannot send negative integers, as it is working in hexadecimal and it has range between 0-255

Comment: I'm afraid that's not true, if it was then no computer would be able to represent negative numbers.  It all depends on the encoding.